# How do I type literal binary in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, binary, literals

How do you type binary literals in VB.NET?

```
&HFF          // literal Hex -- OK
&b11111111    // literal Binary -- how do I do this?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could define it as string and then parse it:

```
myBin = Convert.ToInt32("1010101010", 2)
```

Answer (score 16):

As of VB.NET 15 there is now support for binary literals:

```
Dim mask As Integer = &B00101010
```

You can also include underscores as digit separators to make the number more readable without changing the value:

```
Dim mask As Integer = &B0010_1010
```

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on codymanix's answer... You could wrap this in an Extension on Strings, and add type checking...
something along the lines of:

```
<Extension> Public Function ParseBinary(target As String) As Integer  
    If Not RegEx.IsMatch(target, "^[01]+$") Then Throw New Exception("Invalid binary characters.")  

    Return Convert.ToInt32(target, 2)  
End Function
```

This allows then, anywhere you have a string of binary value, say "100101100101", you can do:

```
Dim val As Integer = "100101100101".ParseBinary()
```

Note that to use <Extension>, you must import **System.Runtime.CompilerServices**, and be running on Framework 3.5 or later.

Comment: That looks mighty useful. Makes me wish I could upgrade to 3.5

Comment: Yah, between Extensions, LINQ and XML literals, ... 3.5 blows away 2.0!  :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

VB.NET supports decimal (without prefix), octal (with `&O` prefix), and hexadecimal (with `&H` prefix) [integer literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711649(VS.71).aspx) directly.

Comment: Is that link dead?

Comment: new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/byte-data-type